# Sample Size and Power Calculation for Ordinal response (Ordinal Logistic Regression)

Tags: sas

I'm working on a study, looking at the impact of Food insecurity on Anti Retroviral Treatment (ART). ART is divided into three ordered groups: poor, fair, good, and Food Insecurity is ordered into four groups: Severely food insecure, Moderately food insecure, Mildly food insecure, Food secure.

I need to calculate sample size and power for this study, and I've looked around, but haven't found clear answers. Some suggestions indicate estimating from binomial logistic, but that method seems debatable.

If it helps Im familiar with SAS Power procedure, but I also welcome suggestions using R as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. What you are looking for is methodology for research question. Stack overflow is purely for coding. You might find better results from dedicated statistics sites.

Comment: Hi pinegulf. Thanks. I'll look into those.